# Centos 7 Two Gateways (virtual and VLAN) question

Tags: centos, ifconfig, gateway

I could not get this working.

I have two public ip addresses . on centos 6 my setup was eth0.2 VLAN2 was DHCP from ISP 1 and eth0:1 was static ip address from ISP 2.

It worked out the box without any configuration, metric or table routes entries.

ON centos 7 I set the ifcfg-eno1.2and ifcfg-eno1:3

```
DEVICE=eno1.2
HWADDR=removed
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=DHCP
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=no
ARPCHECK=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=10

DEVICE=eno1:3
HWADDR=removed
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=no
IPV6INIT=yes
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=no
ARPCHECK=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=11

IPADDR=APUBLICIPADDRESS
PREFIX=25
GATEWAY=THEGATEWAY
DNS1=1.1.1.1
```

When i restart the network services only the first interface works, but if i release the ip  address  eno1:3 starts working.

I tried adding/removing IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=10 on eno1.2 and IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=11 on eno1:3 to no avail

Any tips?

Comment: What exactly do you mean that in Centos 6 it "worked" and in Centos 7 "doesn't work"? What exactly isn't working? Basically, you should **not** expect that you can just connect two interfaces to two ISPs and it will work correctly, because you shouldn't have two different default gateways - if they will have the same metrics, the routing will be confused and you may be unable to connect to anywhere outside your both LANs, and if they will have different metrics, only the lower metric gateway will actually be used, unless it fails.

Comment: Add the output of `ip route show` in the different situations ("restart the network services", "release the ip address") to your question.